# What does writeHead refer to?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at a GroupMe bot template written in nodejs, I have come across the following function call very frequently: `res.writeHead(200);`.  What -- typically -- does `writeHead(200)` do?  Is it short for "write header"?

Comment: [`writeHead()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) is described in the node.js API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes—it writes the response headers, including the status line. `writeHead(200)`, in particular, sends the `200 OK` status code and the default headers.

Answer (score 0):

response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])#
Sends a response header to the request. The status code is a 3-digit HTTP status code, like 404. The last argument, headers, are the response headers. Optionally one can give a human-readable reasonPhrase as the second argument.

Example:

```
var body = 'hello world';

response.writeHead(200, {  'Content-Length': body.length, Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
```

Comment: Please use indents to make your code look different from the other text